# Log Apache Beam WriteToDatastore result to BigQuery - Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, wrapper

I have a very simple pipeline in python

```
 with beam.Pipeline(options=create_pipeline_options(pipeline_args)) as p:
            rows = (p | 'ReadFromBigquery' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=f"{known_args.project}:{known_args.datasetId}.{known_args.tableId}", use_standard_sql=True))
            entities  = (rows | 'GetEntities' >> beam.ParDo(GetEntity()))
            updated = (entities | 'Update Entities' >> beam.ParDo(UpdateEntity()))
            _ = (updated | 'Write To Datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(known_args.project))
```

I want to log which entities have been correctly updated after WriteToDatastore has finished running so I could write them in a bigquery audit table. Ideally it would look something like this

```
successful_entities, failed entities = (updated | 'Write To Datastore' >> WriteToDatastoreWrapper(known_args.project))
 _ = (successful_entities | 'Write Success To Bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=f"{c.audit_table}:{known_args.datasetId}.{known_args.tableId}"))
 _ = (failed_entities| 'Write Failed To Bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=f"{c.audit_table}:{known_args.datasetId}.{known_args.tableId}"))
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Alternatively if the whole batch fails after *n* numbers of retries, is it possible to catch that failure and log which batch has failed (assuming I have some sort of runId to keep track of batches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it can help.

I propose you a solution with a `dead letter queue` before writing the result to `Datastore`.

`Beam` suggests using a dead letter queue in this case, and we can achieve that with `TupleTags`.

You can write it with `Beam` native but the code is verbose.

I created a library in `Beam` `Java` and `Python` called `Asgarde` :

Here the link of the `Python` version : https://github.com/tosun-si/pasgarde

**You can install the package with `pip` :**

```
pip install asgarde==0.16.0
```

With `Asgarde`, you can catch errors in each step of the pipeline, before writing the result with the `IO` (`Datastore` in this case)

Example :

```py
input_teams: PCollection[str] = p | 'Read' >> beam.Create(team_names)

result = (CollectionComposer.of(input_teams)
            .map('Map with country', lambda tname: TeamInfo(name=tname, country=team_countries[tname], city=''))
            .map('Map with city', lambda tinfo: TeamInfo(name=tinfo.name, country=tinfo.country, city=team_cities[tinfo.name]))
            .filter('Filter french team', lambda tinfo: tinfo.country == 'France'))

result_outputs: PCollection[TeamInfo] = result.outputs
result_failures: PCollection[Failure] = result.failures
```

`Asgarde` proposes a wrapper with `CollectionComposer` class instantiated from a `PCollection`.

Then each operator like `map`, `flat_map`, `filter` applies the operation while error handling.

The result of `CollectionComposer` is a `Tuple` with :

- PCollection of successful outputs
- PCollection of `Failure`

`Failure` is an object given by `Asgarde` :

```py
@dataclass
class Failure:
    pipeline_step: str
    input_element: str
    exception: Exception
```

This object gives the current `input_element` concerned by the error and the current `exception`.

`pipeline_step` is the current `name` used for the transformation.

Your pipeline can be adapted in the following way with `Asgarde` :

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=create_pipeline_options(pipeline_args)) as p:
     rows = (p | 'ReadFromBigquery' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=f"{known_args.project}:{known_args.datasetId}.{known_args.tableId}", use_standard_sql=True))

            
     result = (CollectionComposer.of(rows)
                .map('GetEntities', lambda el : get_entity_function(el))
                .map('Update Entities', lambda entity : update_entity_function(entity)))
            
     result_outputs = result.outputs
     result_failures: PCollection[Failure] = result.failures
            
           
     (result_outputs | 'Write To Datastore' >> WriteToDatastore(known_args.project))

     (result_failures 
         | 'Map before Write to BQ' >> beam.Map(failure_to_your_obj_function) 
         | 'Write Failed To Bigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=f"{c.audit_table}:{known_args.datasetId}.{known_args.tableId}"))
```

You can also apply the same logic with `Beam` native, I share you an example from my personal `Github` repository :

https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-python-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/team_league/domain_ptransform/team_stats_transform.py

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will give it a try and let you know this sounds exactly like what I need :)